# Is there built in support for appending Handlers to the set HandlerResolver in JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean?

Tags: java, spring-framework-beans, javax.xml

I'm creating a JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean instance and want to set a HandlerResolver on it to log requests.

```java
@Bean(name="serviceName")
public JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean serviceNameFactory() throws MalformedURLException {
    JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean();
    factory.setHandlerResolver(new CustomHandlerResolver());
}
```

I also have a common library I'm pulling in that has a class which implements BeanPostProcessor and adds it's own custom HandlerResolver:

```java
public class CustomBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if(JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.class.isAssignableFrom(bean.getClass())) {
            ((JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean)bean).setHandlerResolver(new AnotherCustomHandlerResolver());
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `postProcessAfterInitialization` step setting the AnotherCustomHandlerResolver blows away my CustomHandlerResolver.

I've come up with a workaround by extending the `JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean` and using a different custom HandlerResolver that holds onto multiple instances:

JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean extension:

```java
class MultipleHandlerJaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean extends JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean {

    MultipleHandleResolver resolver;

    public MultipleHandlerJaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean() {
        this.resolver = new MultipleHandleResolver();
        // This instance ALWAYS gets the MultipleHandlerResolver as it's resolver
        super.setHandlerResolver(resolver);
    }

    @Override
    public void setHandlerResolver(HandlerResolver handlerResolver) {
        // When setHandlerResolver is called we keep track of that, but don't set it on super
        this.resolver.addResolver(handlerResolver);
    }
}
```

Multiple Handler Resolver:

```java
class MultipleHandleResolver implements HandlerResolver {

    List<HandlerResolver> handlerResolvers;

    public MultipleHandleResolver() {
        this.handlerResolvers = new ArrayList<HandlerResolver>();
    }

    /**
     * When we get the handler chain we now iterate over all of our HandlerResolvers to get their handler chains
     */
    @Override
    public List<Handler> getHandlerChain(PortInfo portInfo) {
        List<Handler> handlerList = new ArrayList<Handler>();
        for (HandlerResolver handlerResolver : this.handlerResolvers) {
            handlerList.addAll(handlerResolver.getHandlerChain(portInfo));
        }
        return handlerList;
    }

    public void addResolver(HandlerResolver resolver) {
        this.handlerResolvers.add(resolver);
    }

}
```

This seems like a lot of trouble just to append handlers to the chain (and it also requires pulling in the custom JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean into my bean configuration). **Is there built in support to do this with the JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean?**